# Finding a specific file in several sub-directories

Tags: find, cp

I've the following problem :

I have to write something to copy a file contained in directory A. The file is unique, and has a specific extension (.jil). Only problem, directory A can contains a sub-directory B (which can contain a sub-directory C, ...) and then my file won't be located in the directory A, but in one of his sub-directories.

What command can I use to find this file without exploring all my directoties ?

Comment: Do you want to copy `foo.jil` wherever it is within `A/` or do you want to _only_ copy `A/foo.jill` and not `A/B/foo.jil`?

Comment: I want to copy foo.jil wherever it's within A/ something like :
find . -name "*.jil" -exec "cp"

Comment: That's how `find` works by default, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually the way `find` works by default. You could just run

```
find A/ -name "*.jil" -exec cp {} target_dir/ \;
```

The default behavior of `find` is to look into all subdirectories recursively, you can control this by setting the `-maxdepth`/`-midepth` options:

```
   -maxdepth levels
          Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of direc‐
          tories below the command line arguments.  -maxdepth 0
           means only apply the tests and  actions  to  the  command  line
          arguments.
   -mindepth levels
          Do  not apply any tests or actions at levels less than levels (a
          non-negative integer).  -mindepth  1  means  process  all  files
          except the command line arguments.
```